# ObservableCollection not working at all

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have this piece of code:

```
private ObservableCollection<Stats> _stats;

public StatisticsViewModel()
{
    Stats = new ObservableCollection<Stats>();
    Stats.Add(new Stats() { Type = "Min", Price = 100, Legend = Legend.Default });
}

public ObservableCollection<Stats> Stats
{
    get 
    { 
        return _stats; 
    }
    set
    {
        if (_stats != value)
        {
            _stats = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Stats");
        }
    }
}
```

When the new collection is created, the set of Stats is called. However, when adding the object, it does not and so it does not execute RaisePropertyChanged...

What could I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Well, you can register a handler for CollectionChanged event of the Stats collection and call `RaisePropertyChanged()` each time. But do you really need it?

Comment: It is working fine, adding an item to the collection does not call the setter, you are essentially calling `Add()` on the collection returning by the getter. If you want to do something when and item is added or removed from the collection then hook in to the `CollectionChanged` event

Comment: Or to put it simpler: why would it raise `PropertyChanged` if the property doesn't change?

Comment: have you actually tried binding that property to some `ItemsSource` of some ItemsControl? I don't think raising propertychanged is a must-do when there is just some item added to the collection.

Comment: Yes, the ItemsSource is set. Still, it does nothing....

Comment: An `ObservableCollection<T>` does not raise the `PropertyChanged` event on its parent object. It raises the `CollectionChanged` event on itself when something is added or removed. WPF knows about `ObservableCollection<T>` and the `CollectionChanged` event, so it works for binding **similar to** the way `PropertyChanged` works. But they are not one in the same.

Comment: So why doesn't my UI get updated when something new is added..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the new collection is created, the set of Stats is called.

Correct.  This is because the code is setting the `Stats` property, which invokes the setter method.

> However, when adding the object, it does not and so it does not execute RaisePropertyChanged

Also correct.  When calling `.Add` on an object the code isn't *setting* the property which holds that object.  So there's no reason for the setter method to be invoked.  The `Stats` property *itself* isn't being changed in this case, you're just interacting with the object.

> What could I do to resolve this issue?

The `ObservableCollection` class [exposes two events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668610(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can subscribe to.  The `CollectionChanged` event is raised when the collection itself changes, and the `PropertyChanged` event is raised when a property value on the collection changes.

For example, if you want to handle the event when the collection changes, you can subscribe to that event:

```
Stats.CollectionChanged += CollectionChangeHandler;

// elsewhere...

private void CollectionChangeHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something to respond to the changed collection
}
```

Comment: But what should I do to update the UI when adding items?

Comment: @Bv202: Well, what do you *want* to do to the UI?  If you want to perform an update manually then you would do it in that `CollectionChangeHandler` method.  Though, WPF subscribes to `ObservableCollection` events automatically, so if used accordingly then it will update automatically.